# Reducible representations of the Clifford Algebra

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras, representation-of-algebras

I would like to construct reducible representations of the Clifford algebra, that consist of $8\times8$ matrices with purely real or purely imaginary elements.

Assume that I am familiar with the Dirac, Majorana and Weyl representations.

Can someone refer me to some book to read, that covers this material?

Thanks in advance